# What type to give flow annotations for onChange etc

Tags: reactjs, flowtype

I have the following component:

```
import { identity } from 'lodash';

export const Input = ({
  onChange = identity
  //etc.
}: {
  onChange: Event<HTMLInputElement>,
}) => <Input onChange={onChange} />
```

But when I run flow I get this error:

```
onChange = identity,
       ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ default value. Expected polymorphic type instead of
onChange = identity,
       ^^^^^^^^ class type: Event
```

I'm confused as to where to find the definition for `Event`.

If I look at facebook's dom types:

I can see [Event](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/dom.js#L213) here which has a [target property](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/dom.js#L224) of type `EventTarget`.

But looking at the `EventTarget` [definition](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/dom.js#L157), I don't see any definiton for value.

I don't see to define the synthetic event so that it has a target of type [HtmlInputElement](https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/master/lib/dom.js#L2740).

Answer (score 15):

As TLadd said, `SyntheticInputEvent` is what you want for the parameter. However it requires a type argument, so you'll need to make it `SyntheticInputEvent<HTMLInputElement>`.

Answer (score 7):

I would take a look at the flow doc:

https://flow.org/en/docs/frameworks/react/#adding-types-for-react-events-a-classtoc-idtoc-adding-types-for-react-events-hreftoc-adding-types-for-react-eventsa

You'd want something like this:

```
class MyComponent extends React.Component {
  onChange(event: Event & { currentTarget: HTMLInputElement }) {
    // ...
  }
}
```

Comment: This deserves to be the accepted answer! It is more informative than the official docs for this situation.

Answer (score 3):

Flow has built in definitions for synthetic events. The one you would want in this case is SyntheticInputEvent (https://github.com/facebook/flow/blob/v0.49.1/lib/react.js#L310)

So the type of onChange would be

```
{ 
   onChange: (SyntheticInputEvent) => mixed,
}
```

A function that takes in a SyntheticInputEvent and returns a mixed time, which basically just means that you don't care what the function returns (if anything).

Answer (score 2):

**onChange** event might look like this (notice using **currentTarget** instead of **target**):

```
onChange = (e: SyntheticInputEvent<HTMLInputElement>): void => {
    this.setState({ value: e.currentTarget.value });
}
```

Comment: What is the purpose of SyntheticInputEvent<HTMLInputElement> and how does it work here?

Answer (score 1):

For React Native:

```
import { type SyntheticEvent } from "react-native/Libraries/Types/CoreEventTypes";
type TextInputEvent = SyntheticEvent<{ value: string }>;
```

Than you can just use it:
`onChange: (TextInputEvent) =>`